# USB Mice not working, but USB Keyboard is

Tags: 18.04, mouse

I am new to Linux based operating systems, and I decided to dual (boot/load?) Windows 10 and version 18.04 of Ubuntu. I am not booting from a USB as I do not have one available. It is being dual booted from my harddisk.

I have tried several mice, all of which work on Windows 10 (including the one I'm using currently, which is just a plain, $10 Logitech mouse from Walmart) but they do not want to work on Ubuntu.

Upon getting to the Ubuntu OS screen—where one can see the icons, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>, etc.—my mouse is frozen in the bottom right-hand side of the screen. My mouse will light up for a few minutes, and then turn off. This happened to all of my mice, regardless of what USB port it was in. I am able to use keyboard commands.

Is there anything I can do to get my mice working in Ubuntu?

As I said, and I feel like it's worth repeating: all of my mice (three of them) work completely fine on two laptops and my desktop while on Windows 10. There are only issues when I am loaded onto Ubuntu.

I do not consider this to be a duplicate question, as none of the other questions of this sort answered it in such a way that solved my problem.

Comment: You have said you are using the latest version of Ubuntu, which is Ubuntu 18.10 (2018.October release), but have tagged 18.04 (2018.April release) so please confirm you version.  I would also suggest adding the command & output of `lsusb` (list usb devices) to your question (edit it & add there, not as a comment please, and when mouse is attached of course)

Comment: Apologies, it is indeed 18.04. I will correct it.

Comment: Better yet, if I'm troubleshooting a usb device, I `lsusb >before.txt` ie. save the list of usb devices to a text file, add the device I want to diagnose, then `lsusb >after.txt` to get that info, then `diff before.txt after.txt` to see the differences.  (filenames are examples only)  This maybe helpful for you for each mouse - confirm it's recognized, and how mouse-device identifies itself to the OS...  *just a thought*

Comment: Look at your BIOS settings for USB and see if it's set for `legacy`. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: Yes, it is set to legacy @heynnema

Comment: Boot to a Ubuntu Live DVD/USB and see if the USB mouse works there. Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I already had tried booting from a USB. Same result. @ heynnema

Comment: Any difference booting from a Ubuntu Live 18.10 DVD/USB?

Comment: Exact same problem here :( Logitech USB mouse M705 works fine on Ubuntu 17.10. On Ubuntu 18.10 the mouse flicks on and off. Very frustrating :( How can something so basic as a USB mouse break between two releases of Ubuntu?